# Validate a numeric string has a fixed amount of chars

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

I'm trying to use a validator to validate that the field cedula is a numeric string but also have 10 chars.

For example:

132456 Would not be validated because it is a numeric string but only has 6 chars

1315987423 Would be validated because it is a numeric string and has 10 chars

131598742B Would not be validated because it isn't a numeric string because of the B in the end

Im trying to validate it like this in the validator

```
'cedula' => ['required', 'numeric', 'size:10'],
```

But it only allows me to input the value of `10` and not a numeric string of 10 chars like 1315987423 that is what I desire to validate

How can I make the validator do what I need to do in this case?
Cedula is a string, not an int

Edit: Already realized that I should use digits to validate what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34527/como-valido-con-laravel-que-un-campo-sea-solo-numerico) about your question.

I supose that this is the info which you are loocking for.

`'cedula' =>  'numeric|required|unique:personas|min:100000|max:99999999',`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
'cedula' => ['required', 'digits:10'],
```

> The integer under validation must have an exact length of value.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-digits